# How to center crop splash screen using windowBackground attribute in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, drawable, android-styles

Graphic designer who I work with provided full-screen splash screen image. I was asked to use it in a way, that it works as if it was `ImageView` with scaleType set to `centerCrop`. I also was asked to show this image immedietely when app starts.

So, I tried to set application splash screen via `windowBackground` attribute, but it's stretched as if scaletype was `fitXY` (in `ImageView` terminology). People all over internet use that, or use drawable resource with app icon centered and background set to certain color, as described in this article: https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565

So my question is - Is it possible to achieve `centerCrop` behaviour when using `windowBackground`, so it works as below:

(Original provided fullscreen image on the left. **Black border** indicates device resolution)

[image]

Note I can't use activity layout for splash screen.